# How to pass multiple specific fields of an object as props to an Angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript

Say I have a component `app-item` rendered in an `app-list`:

```html
<!-- list.component.html -->
<app-item *ngFor="let product of products" />
```

It accepts dozens of props like `title`, `description`, `url` etc. The props are based off a type `Product`, but the component doesn't need every field of the `product` object, only some of them.

**What is the best way to pass these props?**

I wish there was a one-liner like:

```html
<app-item 
  *ngFor="let product of products" 
  [item]="product | filterProps"
/>
```

The most obvious way to do this is to just.. specify every prop in the `.ts` file one by one, but then you end up with a wall of 20-30 props in your template. Totally unreadable

I tried declaring a type in the `item.component.ts` like so:

```
@Input() item: Pick<Product,
  | 'title'
  | 'description'
  | 'url'
>;
```

Which now directly points to the fields of the `Product` type, which is great, but i still have to specify all of them in the HTML or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own `filterProps` Pipe which lets you exactly do what you want:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'filterProps', standalone: true, pure: true })
export class FilterPropsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
    value: T,
    ...props: K[]
  ): Pick<T, K> {
    return props.reduce((result, prop) => {
      if (prop in value) {
        result[prop] = value[prop];
      }
      return result;
    }, {} as Pick<T, K>);
  }
}
```

This pipe can be used like this:

```
<app-item 
  *ngFor="let product of products" 
  [item]="product | filterProps : 'title':'description':'url'"
/>
```

**Demo**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uufxra?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Or parhaps use the ellipsis `transform(value: any, ...props: string[])` which would allow you to write `product | filterProps: 'title', 'description', 'url'`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I updated my answer because it's a bit less code to write the props. Between the props you have to use a colon and not a comma for giving multiple arguments to the pipe.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach make it less performant? If i remember correctly, pipes are optimized in a different way than normal props